# .htaccess - Authenticate incoming connection based on dynamic DNS address (similar to static IP authentication)

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, dns

I have a dynamic IP fibre connection that cant be upgraded to a static IP.

I have a small web app i need to deploy which has some IOT devices connecting to it. The IOT devices have no option for authentication into the web app other than coming from the static IP. But my internet connection has a dynamic IP.

Ive been looking at dynamic DNS services like dyn or no-ip. Is it possible to configure the `.htaccess` file for the web app to authenticate a connection based on the connections incoming dynamic dns ?

Im familar with how to do it if you are trying to authenticate based on Static IP, but not sure where to start with a dynamic dns

Comment: Just going to mention that authenticating based on an IP address is a **bad** idea. Especially since IP addresses can be spoofed. Don't use IP based authentication for anything that has any importance.

Comment: Good point @tambre

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html for `Require host`.